# Updates won't install

Tags: updates

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04, but now updates will not install. This is the error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

linux-image-generic-lts-saucy: Depends: linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic but it is not installed
```

I have tried several of the terminal commands listed among the AskUbuntu answers, but get:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13 - Permission denied)
E: unable to lock the administration directory
```

The `apt-get -f install` doesn't fix the problem.

I am not a code monkey, so would someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: first remove the lock file `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`.Before doing this, make sure that no other installation process is running on the background.Now try `sudo apt-get install -f` and post it's output.

Comment: I notice that a package with a `saucy` extension is trying to be installed. Why would that happen if you are not upgrading to 13.10?

Comment: Neither of the suggestions worked. The updates will not install with the same error. After the suggested commands were entered, this was the result: 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33~precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
I don't know why the "saucy" extensions were trying to be installed. It just happened. If this question is a duplicate, where can I find the other answers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `sudo apt-get install <packages>`.

This usually solves most of the `Permission Denied` problems.